# how to replace file in ear using unix

Tags: unix, jar

I have a sample.ear file and I want to replace a particular file inside sample.ear.

```
consider ear file sample.ear which content com1/test1/file1.sh and com2/file2.sh
```

here I want to replace file1.sh with updated file file1.sh using unix.

I am using jar command but i am not able to replace the file in subdirectories

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
jar -xf sample.ear com1/test1/file1.sh
```

to extract `file.sh`. Once you are done modifying this `com1/test1/file1.sh` file use:

```
jar -uf sample.ear com1/test1/file1.sh
```

to update the archived ear with the modified file.

Use `jar --help` for detailed help.

Comment: Should we move to the jar location using cd command? Also should we use .class extension for class file?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do with the extracted file but in general yes

Comment: Can you please answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627541/shell-script-to-replace-a-class-file)?