# Shell script to replace a class file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I have read many posts about changing the contents of a file and replace the whole file, but little did I understand.
Referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093258/how-to-replace-file-in-ear-using-unix) too. The *.sh* is the one that confuses me. Do I need to use *.sh* in my case too. I don't want to ruin the project by trying something new, without much understanding.

How do I replace a class file in a jar? I have the class file ready from my workspace. All I need to do is replace the already present class file in the jar. Moreover, need I restart the server after replacing, to see effects?
The application server that we are using is IBM websphere.
Should I also navigate to my ear file location in the server? For example, cd aaa/bbb/ccc and then execute the command.
Please help, I am totally new to this.

Comment: Please let me know if there is anything required in my question. I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To extract/pull a particular class from your ear:

```
jar -xf sample.ear com/sample/Example.class
```

then overwrite `com/sample/Example.class` with your generated class and finally do:

```
jar -uf sample.ear com/sample/Example.class
```

To update the ear file again with updated class file.

**PS:** This will require you to deploy the ear file again on your app server and then restart the app server. I would also suggest looking into `ant` or `maven` for this task.

Comment: Thank you for the answer? Is there a way to avoid restarting of server, because many people are working in the server simultaneously?

Comment: Which app server it is? Most of the app servers have hot-deploy options but they all have different setups.

Comment: Edited question accordingly. IBM websphere

Comment: Alright, unfortunately I haven't worked on websphere so you will have to check the reference for more help on that.

Answer (score -1):

.sh file is an example of one of the file from jar that you wish to extract it from jar and edit the extracted file and then again archive it back to the jar... in [EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093258/how-to-replace-file-in-ear-using-unix)

so you don't need .sh if your file name is not ending with .sh..

Comment: So can you please edit your answer to be specific to my case? It will help others when they visit this page.

Comment: Sorry EXAMPLE LINK was wrong...    http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse/